# How to represent and image where grey-scale corresponds to overdense region, and dashed contours to underdense region

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

[image]

This is the density field presented by log (grey-scale corresponds to overdense region, and dashed contours to underdense region. The solid contour represents the mean density）

And in my data, I showed the heat map like that

[image]

[image]

And I also tried use contour() in plot,

It seems not promising. If I want to show a map like the first one, what function should I use?

Comment: You can try to check the borders of those contours and make a shape and fill it? You need to check the masking tools.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example, that is based on the examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_masked.html) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib import colormaps
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

delta = 0.01

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

# get the mean of Z (say the density)
md = np.mean(Z)

# first create a masked version of Z to plot as a grey scale image
overdense = Z.copy()
overdense[Z < md] = np.ma.masked

ax.imshow(
    overdense,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    origin="lower",
    extent=[x[0], x[-1], y[0], y[-1]],
    cmap=colormaps["Greys"],
    norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=md, vmax=np.max(Z)),
)

# over plot the contours for the over dense and underdense regions
# (I'm defining the underdense contours to be 0.1 less than the mean density)
ax.contour(x, y, Z, levels=[md - 0.1, md], colors="k")

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]